# How to get filepath with Uri without "file:///"

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I get an image path with Uri, which is used as the source path in a report. This image is also loaded in an imagebox. The problem is that Uri adds "file:///" to the path. Therefore the image cannot be displayed on the report. How can I get the image path without that portion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Uri.LocalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx):

> Gets a local operating-system representation of a file name.

Just tested this in fsi:

> > let u = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/Public/Test.png");;
>
> val u : Uri = file:///C:/Users/Public/Test.png
>
> > u.LocalPath;;
>
> val it : string = "C:\Users\Public\Test.png"

Looks good.

Comment: +1. Note that is is good idea to check if the `Uri` is indeed file path by checking schema or `IsUnc`/`IsFile` properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove "file:///" from Uri try:

```
string uriPath =... //your path with "file:///" 

string path = uriPath.Replace("file:///", "");
```